# Taylor coefficients for a function taken to its 1/x-th power.

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, power-series, binomial-coefficients

Suppose I have an analytic function $f$ defined by some Taylor series around $x=0$, such that
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n. $$

I now wish to consider the Taylor expansion of
$$(1+f(x))^{1/x} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty b_m x^m, $$
and would like to express the coefficients $b_m$ in terms of $a_n$.

A first attempt using binomial expansion gives:
$$ (1+f(x))^{1/x} = 1 + \frac{1}{x}f(x) + \frac{1}{2x}(\frac{1}{x}-1)f^2(x)+ \frac{1}{3!x}(\frac{1}{x}-1)(\frac{1}{x}-2)f^3(x) \dots  $$
but it's not clear to me what the $b_m$ is from this.

Comment: I would start with $(1+f(x))^{1/x} = \exp( \frac 1x \ln(1+f(x))$.

Comment: Using @MartinR's hint, just try with  a few terms to see how complicated are the first $b_m$.